# Splash Screen Language / Localization Support Not Working, Anything Else Needed?

Tags: iphone, localization, splash-screen

After a bit of research, and have tried this, but it is not working for some reason.  Here is the setup..

In the "root" of the app there is a Default.png and a Default@2x.png.  These seem to be working fine.

In the ru.lproj directory right under the "root" directory....copies of the Default files with small changes.  The files are confirmed to be loaded on the iPhone....etc.

When the language is set to russian, it loads the high level splash instead of the russian screen.

Anything else that has to be done for this to work properly?

Platform is SDK 4.3

Comment: Downvoting after what, 5 years?  Really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want it to be localized: none of it should be in the root, both of them should be in a localized folder, one for ru, one for english (or else)

you should do it via xCode:
in xCode select the splash screen file in the left part of your project and press "apple+i" (or press the blue "info" button in toolbar;

then in the opened window press the left-bottom button "make file localizable", then add all the language you want... you will get as many folder in finder... now just modify the file in the folders for "ru", "en" or else...

Comment: Thanks will try, but I have been told / read to have a version in the root if the user selects a language that is not supported.

Comment: @ort11: no, that's wrong, you just need to specify "Localization native development region" in yourAppInfo.plist file, setting it to a language which is present, usually "en", so it will be used for all language not expressly localized by you...